# User with 2 accounts editing own posts

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits, duplicate-accounts

While reviewing suggested edit queue I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204184/get-pvt-packet-from-usb-gps-in-android-app)

In this question user has asked a question which seems fine, but this question is edited and that editor has added much information. But the edit is proposed by the same user using different account (he is using same profile image for both accounts).

I want to know whether [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13533258) should be approved or rejected.

Comment: When in doubt, choose "Skip".

Comment: @S.L.Barth The problem with "skip" is it just boots OP's question down the road.  At some point, someone needs to make a decision about the suggested edit, and that someone will have just as much information as OP.  "skip" really only works when there is someone else that will have more information (for example, if I know nothing about a particular tag).

Comment: @Teepeemm At some point, that "someone else" may well be the OP. And that is someone who does have the required information.

Comment: @S.L.Barth You can't assume that a specific person will come across a suggested edit in the queue (and in this case, it'd be impossible because of the reputation).  If you're planning on a specific person, then you should message that person to let them know what's happening (as happened here).

Comment: @Teepeemm err... OP is *always* notified of suggested edits in their own posts.

Comment: @Teepeemm: The OP also has the power to singlehandedly accept or reject the edit.

Comment: I'm more interested about the "legacity" of the same user having two accounts than in the review itself. It is allowed?

Comment: @albciff Running multiple accounts is allowed, but you have to keep them separate. Don't use them to do anything that you couldn't do with only a single account. Especially don't vote for your own posts.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I can't imagine a licit situation or proposit where you need to have two accounts, but thanks for explain that it's allowed `:)`

Comment: @albciff One reason is chatbots. The Smoke Detector chatbot, which catches spam, is run from somebody's secondary account. Another is privacy. For example, if you're on both Stack Overflow and Politics.SE, you might want to do that using separate accounts - because if customers or employers Google your SO name, you'd want them to find your professional image, not your political leanings.

Comment: @S.L.Barth ohh chatbots, it's a good reason `:)`. However I don't think privacy it's a good one in the sense you explain; you can have and account for one of the sites in the SE network but this account doesn't need to belong to all sites then you can have one user for SO and a different one for Politics.SE but not both have SO account.

Comment: @albciff i can imagine torvalds not wanting all of his posts to be burdened by his reputation, or some user or other wanting to separate work and personal media presences.

Comment: People use SE for work?

Answer (score 60):

This edit should be rejected as "clearly conflicts with author's intent". You can't know if these two accounts belong to the same person.

You can also comment on that post to tell that person that they should edit their question using the same account.

Comment: I also did that but it seems like a way for gaining reputation

Comment: @VivekMishra I don't think this one is meant for voting fraud. If it was, they'd have Approved the edit from the posting account - instant +2 rep. And they probably wouldn't have used the same profile picture.

Comment: @S.L.Barth ok,so only appropriate action is to reject that edit,I was not aware about this instant +2 rep thing. I thought every edit goes through review queue

Comment: @VivekMishra Every edit by a user below 2000 points goes through the queue. But the OP has a binding vote. If the OP approves an edit, then it is approved immediately - regardless of what the other reviewers choose.

Comment: @S.L.Barth He could just be really bad at running sock puppets lol...

Comment: Has there been any activity on the first account since he started using the second? It may just be someone who can't get back into the first account... (or only has the cookie on his work machine and is editing from home).

Comment: And comment that he can have his accounts merged

Answer (score 37):

I'd reject it.

Same profile picture as the OP, but this could also be impersonation.

Either way, someone shouldn't be using two accounts on here, like that.

Comment: yes but the type of details he has added in edit, also points to the same person

Comment: That's usually the case, when impersonating someone. The point is, we can't be __certain__ it's the same person. He should use the _same account_ as he used to ask the question.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, this happens somewhat frequently when doing suggested edit reviews. In some cases it is people with multiple accounts or RL friends/colleagues that share the same problem. In other cases, it is just some crazy person who thinks it is a great idea add random stuff to someone else's question.

Since we cannot know which is the case, always reject such edits.